# Can I publish my Master's thesis while my supervisor is marking it

Tags: publications, publishers

My supervisor has not finished marking my master's thesis. 
Am I allowed to publish it in a journal before he finishes marking it? I asked him the question  twice, but he never replied to me.

Comment: Perhaps he considers the question as pending while he is marking it? Perhaps he wants to check whether it is up to scratch?

Comment: Sure, but you may regret it if the supervisor finds a problem.

Comment: Definitely!  Your thesis reflects your supervisor's research standard.  In other words, if your supervisor approves, that means your thesis is up his/her standard.  A poor thesis simply conveys the fact that your supervisor/you/uni produce poor research or has a sub-par research culture.  Do you want to be associated with that fact forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your advisor will be coauthor in whatever paper you write that is based on your thesis. In such case, you need their approval of the manuscript before submitting it for publication.

If you are considering submitting for publication and you are not considering putting your advisor as a coauthor, I would strongly encourage against it if the norm in your field is to include your advisor. If your advisor has already signaled that they do not feel comfortable being an author, you should strongly reevaluate whether your work is worthy of publication before submitting it for publication.

Comment: Advisor as co-author is very field-dependent. In my field, math, this would be extremely unusual, in fact.

Comment: Also uncommon in philosophy for advisors to co-author student theses. (and the "incorporated" version seems pretty jumbled at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I was in a very similar situation to yours. I wanted to publish my master's dissertation before I handed it in. In the end I decided to do one thing at a time - submit it to uni first and then ask for approval to publish from my supervisor, which is what I did. I missed one journal deadline because of this but I thought it was the right thing to do.

I did get approval pretty quickly after that so I submitted it for publication a couple of months before the mark came in and in time for the journal's next deadline. In your case I would wait for approval before you submit for publication because your relationship with your supervisor pre and post degree result is of great importance. I know only too well the urge to submit for publication but it's important that you get the green light first. I can't see a reason why you'd be denied it, but I would personally retain a good working relationship and wait. If you have a pressing deadline, write again and copy in another departmental member, or go in and see them.